# How to refactor this particular Reactjs code so it's complies with Eslint

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm a Reactjs Beginner and read lots of code and stumble on this.
I want to change this code so it comply with Estlint, that is:

> "Arrow function should not return assignment"

I read the [docs](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign) and it's no big deal but they dont mention this particular case.

I have tried to create the react-slick `Slider`beforehand somehow to try to get a ref to it but dont know how to do it. Like creating a class variable `Sliter` and then make the `this.slider = slider` but it gives lots of error

[image]

This is the file

```
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-props-no-spreading */
import Slider from 'react-slick';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.css';
import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css';
import React from 'react';
import Resume from '../../resume.json';
import albums from '../../albumData.json';

const la = require('lodash');

    class SliderWrapper extends React.Component {
        shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
            // certain condition here, perhaps comparison between this.props and nextProps
            // and if you want to update slider on setState in parent of this, return true, otherwise return false
            const { updateCount } = nextProps;
            const { updateCounter } = this.props;
    
            if (updateCounter !== updateCount) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    
        sliders() {
            return Resume.weeks.map(week => {
                let photo = la.find(albums, { weekNumber: week.weekNumber });
                photo = encodeURIComponent(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/images/weeks/${week.weekNumber}/${photo.coverImage}`);
                const { onImageClick } = this.props;
    
                return (
                    // Timeline items
                    <section className="timeline-carousel" key={week.weekNumber}>
                        <h1>week {week.weekNumber}</h1>
                        <div className="timeline-carousel__item-wrapper" data-js="timeline-carousel">
                            <div className="timeline-carousel__item">
                                <div className="timeline-carousel__image">
                                    <img onClick={() => onImageClick(week.weekNumber)} alt="CoverImage" src={photo} />
                                    <h2>UNDER CONSTRUCTION IN PROGRES..</h2>
                                </div>
                                <div className="timeline-carousel__item-inner">
                                    <div className="pointer" />
                                    <span className="year">{week.year}</span>
                                    <span className="month">{week.albumDate}</span>
                                    <p>{week.summary}</p>
                                    <a href="#/" className="read-more">
                                        Read more, Dev should go to read more
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                );
            });
        }
    
        render() {
            const { afterChanged } = this.props;
            const { beforeChanged } = this.props;
            const settings = {
                dots: false,
                arrows: false,
                autoplay: false,
                infinite: true,
                lazyLoad: false,
                swipeToSlide: true,
                centerMode: false,
                focusOnSelect: false,
                className: 'center',
                slidesToShow: 4,
                afterChange: afterChanged,
                beforeChange: beforeChanged,
                responsive: [
                    {
                        breakpoint: 1024,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 3,
                            slidesToScroll: 3,
                            infinite: false,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 600,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 2,
                            slidesToScroll: 2,
                            initialSlide: 2,
                        },
                    },
                    {
                        breakpoint: 480,
                        settings: {
                            slidesToShow: 1,
                            slidesToScroll: 1,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            };
            return (
                <div>
                    <Slider ref={slider => (this.slider = slider)} {...settings}>
                        {this.sliders()}
                    </Slider>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    
    export default SliderWrapper;
```

Comment: What does it do if you swap those paren's for curly braces?

Comment: @RobertP Thanks the Eslint warning is gone but what exactly happened here

Answer (score 0):

By just using parens there, the code creates a function that returns a value. So essentially, you're actually writing a function like this:

```js
// example of what's generated with parens; don't do this!
function assignRef(slider) {
  return this.slider = slider;
}
// and later...
<Slider ref={assignRef} {...settings}>
  {this.sliders()}
</Slider>
```

Which is not what should be used here. Use Curly Braces instead

```js
<Slider ref={slider => {this.slider = slider}} {...settings}>
  {this.sliders()}
</Slider>

// example of what's generated with curly braces, do not actually use.
// function assignRef(slider) {
//   this.slider = slider;
// }
```

which is what you're looking for.

Comment: This answer is probably confusing the op even more... You should also state what he should do and use an arrow function in the context he has, otherwise this will never work with `this`